# Change status bar color when navigation bar is hidden

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch

I want to set black color(bar tint color) of status bar and white tint color when navigation bar is hidden.

And I want it for specific views. I have tried this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() 
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

}
```

I also tried this thing: I set the value to NO in  P-list for View controller-based status bar appearance.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to change the status bar color, you can use

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent
```

Keep in mind you cannot set the status bar color to anything other than LightContent and the default (black). You can however set the status bar to light and throw an element behind it with a different color.

If you want a true way to override the color to make it black (default) or light, you can also try

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

In the view controllers you want to override. If you need a different background color, throw a UILabel behind it with a color and specify light content or default as the color.

Comment: Also note, you will need to specify this in each view controller, as if you trigger that code in one view and not the other, since it's using the UIApplication layer, it will affect all other views unless otherwise specified.

Comment: I want it for specific views, not for whole storyboard. I will try your trick of throwing an element behind with a different color.

Comment: I tried this trick. The status bar becomes black but it hides the time,carrier and battery signal. I want to make tint color white.

Comment: This will only make status bar black. But the battery sign, time and carrier will be hidden as they are also black by default. Tell me a way to make them white on black status bar.

Answer (score 1):

Just write these two lines in `viewdidload`

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
```

and paste this function anywhere in that `ViewController` class

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
   return .lightContent
}
```